# For this Method is an object reference necessary

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. I wonder why I get errors for this:

Error: For this method a Object-Reference is necessary (translated from the German Message). Any Ideas. Seems to be correct for me.

```
namespace DNS
{

    public class Core
    {

        Dig dig;

        public Core()
        {
            dig = new Dig();
        }


        public static void startTest()
        {
            dig.myServer = "10.10.10.10"; <------ ERROR
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to access the instance `dig` field in a static method which is not possible because you need an instance of an object in order to access instance members.

One possibility is to make the `dig` field static:

```
public class Core
{
    private static Dig dig = new Dig();

    public static void startTest()
    {
        dig.resolver.DnsServer = "10.10.10.10";
        ...
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to make the `startTest` method and instance method:

```
public class Core
{
    private Dig dig;

    public Core()
    {
        dig = new Dig();
    }

    public void startTest()
    {
        dig.resolver.DnsServer = "10.10.10.10";
        ...
    }
}
```

or yet another possibility is to create an instance of the `Core` object in the static method:

```
public class Core
{
    private Dig dig;

    public Core()
    {
        dig = new Dig();
    }

    public static void startTest()
    {
        Core core = new Core();
        core.dig.resolver.DnsServer = "10.10.10.10";
        ...
    }
}
```

It will depend on your actual design requirements.

Comment: In the first snippet, `startTest` should still be `static`, right?  You might also want to illustrate using an instance field from an instance other than `this`, right now your first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes it should be static.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize Dig inside of your static method.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make the entire class static. Then your error disappears as well:

namespace ADDNS 
{

```
public static class Core 
{ 

    Dig dig; 

    public static Core() 
    { 
        dig = new Dig(); 
    } 


    public static void startTest() 
    { 
        dig.resolver.DnsServer = "10.10.10.10";// <------ ERROR 
    }
```

}
}